# what is the mean of *\ in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched Python dictionary but nothing came out.

what is the mean of *\ in the below code?

```
    def __init__(self, input_dim=(1, 28, 28), 
                 conv_param={'filter_num':30, 'filter_size':5, 'pad':0, 'stride':1},
                 hidden_size=100, output_size=10, weight_init_std=0.01):
        filter_num = conv_param['filter_num']
        filter_size = conv_param['filter_size']
        filter_pad = conv_param['pad']
        filter_stride = conv_param['stride']
        input_size = input_dim[1]
        conv_output_size = (input_size - filter_size + 2*filter_pad) / filter_stride + 1
        pool_output_size = int(filter_num * (conv_output_size/2) * (conv_output_size/2))

        #weight initialize
        self.params = {}
        self.params['W1'] = weight_init_std * \
                            np.random.randn(filter_num, input_dim[0], 5, 5)

#and so on
```

in

```
self.params['W1'] = weight_init_std * \
                            np.random.randn(filter_num, input_dim[0], 5, 5)
```

?

Comment: In your case `*` means multiply and `\\` means the next line is part of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as

```
self.params['W1'] = weight_init_std * np.random.randn(filter_num, input_dim[0], 5, 5)
```

`*` stands for multiplication.
The trailing `\` is for newline continuation. It informs python that the current expression does not end in this line.

Comment: oh was simple line break... thank you...